# Select 1 row per group by based on multiple criteria

Tags: sql, postgresql

Out of a large dataset I'm trying to select 1 row for each `property_id` based on two criteria

- first: the row with the most recent `recording_date`
- second: if the most recent `recording_date` is shared by multiple records then take the one with the highest sale price (if any)

A sample of the data looks like this, table name: `deeds`

```
id                                   | property_id                          | recording_date | sale_price 
9bf7de90-0b3f-40b0-83bb-9392831a03a3 | 002bb6d2-e064-4eb4-adc2-45713836dfe1 | 2005-12-22     | 535000     
30725c07-b4ab-484b-b09e-30592716340b | 002bb6d2-e064-4eb4-adc2-45713836dfe1 | 2017-09-27     |            
c194b85a-3fb3-46e0-94f0-eeaba1e961e4 | 002bb6d2-e064-4eb4-adc2-45713836dfe1 | 2017-09-27     | 566000
```

(I'm using Postgres if that matters)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Use `distinct on`:

```
select distinct on (property_id) t.*
from t
order by property_id, recording_date desc, sales_price desc nulls last
```

Comment: Thanks very much for the answer! I had to add `recording_date desc` to get the most recent `recording_date` so not sure if you might want to update the answer but other than that it worked great. Thanks again!